# Do mongols have something like a werewolf?

Tags: monsters, werewolves, mongolian-shamanism

Lots of cultures have some sort of shapeshifting monster or a magician that can transform into animals.

Do mongols have something like this too?

Is it a feral monster or is it more intelligent?

Is the transformation voluntary?

Is it a curse or a blessing or a spell or punishment or demonic possession?